# How many amperes and watts do I need for this setup?

Tags: power-supply, computer-building, power-consumption

I'm trouble calculating how many amperes I need for this setup. I know I need around 500-600W, but my current PSU is 600W but only has 14A on the +12V rail and I don't know if it can run this new system.

Processor is AMD X4 750K [link](http://www.cpu-world.com/CPUs/Bulldozer/AMD-Athlon%20II%20X4%20750K.html)
Motherboard is MSI FM2-A85XA-G43 [link](http://www.msi.com/product/mb/FM2-A85XA-G43.html)
GPU is Sapphire HD 7790 1GB DDR5 (can't post any more links)
RAM is 1 stick of DDR3 4GB
HDDs: 3 regular S-ATAs, and 1 combo dvd/cd drive
I also have two 80mms fans and two 120mms fans in the case, along with a front bay display and fan controller.

Is this calculation correct?

100 W + 85 W + 10W *3 + 5W * 2 + 1.68W * 2 + 5W   = 233.6W
CPU TDP + GPU TDP + HDD + 120mm fan = total wattage
W/V = I, therefore 233.6W/12v rail = 19.4amps?

Thanks in advance?

Comment: A 600W power supply will have no problem with your setup.

Comment: even if it has only 14A on the +12V rail?

Comment: There is nothing you have installed that would indicate you would have a problem with AMPs

Comment: What do the components say they draw from the +12V rail?

Answer (score 1):

No, your computation is not correct, you are neglecting the (very important) internal resistance of your components, which acts in parallel to that of your rail.

So, let us call I1 and R1 current and resistance in the rail, and I2 and R2 current and resistance in the pc. Since the resistances are in parallel, we know that

```
   I1 R1 = I2 R2
```

but we also know that we have a V volt rail (V=12 in your case). Then we also have

```
   I1 R1 = V
```

Lastly, the power absorption in the pc is W, which of course is given by

```
   W = I2^2 R2
```

These are three equations, with three known quantities (V,W, R1) and three unknowns (I2, I1, R2). Obviously, they can always be solved, even if W were to be outrageously large. Since it can be shown from the above equations that

```
  R2 = V^2/W
```

we see that, even for W >>1 there is a solution provided R2 is very small. You also see from this that it is important that R2 be small, but non-zero, otherwise you could not satisfy the first equation above.